# How to update values to the Dataset

Tags: winforms

I'm working on windows form project, added service based library and created a table in it.

Just by dragging the table from the DataSources window i get the textboxes which show the values in the table.

When i start debugging, the form window appears and i enter values and click the save button on the top.

Sometimes it thrown exception.(Db is read-only). After changing permission, now when i click save button, nothing happens and in the table i find no new values.

Where is the problem?[image]